# I start with the good and end with the bad

Tags: word, wordplay

## I start with the good and end with the bad

> I start with the good and end with the (sort-of?) bad

> My second letters spell poet

> I rhyme with rest

### Old Clues:

> I am a third like the fourth state of matter

> I am a third like what math puns make me feel

> I am a third like the blank: C U IN THE _ _ _ _ _ _

> That's Spanish, dude! Now translate it to English

Comment: The first word is plasma, the second word is number, and the blank should be nt, are these correct? So the answer is a six letter word, that contains two letters from the first word and two letters from the second word, and it ends in nt?

Comment: No, the blank can't be nt, the blank should have six letters, the last hint is unclear.

Comment: @Ξένη ΓήινοςI think the third word is rot13(pbfzbf), but I have no idea about the rest of the puzzle

Comment: Did xyldke get the right answer? If yes, could you explain the Spanish clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### New Cues and Solution

The word you're looking for is

> protest

> I start with the good

> Pro, someone who is good at what they do (pro gamer)

> and end with the (sort-of?) bad

> Test, which can be considered bad, if it is very hard or you didn't study enough.

> My second letters spell poet

> **p**r**o**t**e**s**t**

> I rhyme with rest

> Test rhymes with rest, so protest does as well.

##### Old Clues

I am a third like the fourth state of matter

> That's **PLASMA**

I am a third like what math puns make me feel

> Puns make me feel numb, but maths puns make me feel **NUMBER**

I am a third like the blank: C U IN THE _ _ _ _ _ _

> There's a book called ["See You in the **COSMOS**"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/See_You_in_the_Cosmos), the description of which sounds perfect for English class.

My idea:

> All of these words have six letters, so a third of them would each be two letters.
>  If we take two letters from each word to form a new one, the new one will be 1/3 like each of the other words.
>  I tried splitting the words into two letter particles, those being:
>   "PL" "AS" "MA"
>   "NU" "MB" "ER"
>   "CO" "SM" "OS"
>  I tried combining these particles into new words and translating the result from Spanish to English (as per the next line).

The problem:

> The only words google translator can translate are:
>   aseros - handles
>   manuos - manuals
>   mambos - mambos (dances)
>   erasos - erased
>   oseras - bear caves
>   comear - eat
>   None of these options make any particular sense. And my rudimentary knowledge of Spanish makes me doubt that some of them are even words.
>  I suspect I can't just cleanly slice the words into three to get the thirds but haven't had time to check every possible combination yet. Also, before I do that, I'd like some indication that I'm on the right track

Comment: The words are correct, and I confess the final answer is hard.

Comment: Would the 1/3 criteria be preserved, if the combined word included a letter that is present in more than one of the other words? (i.e. "combas", which could be up to 1/2 of the first, 1/3 of the second and 2/3 of the third word)

Comment: No, each of them has 2 common letters (in the correct spot)

Comment: I shouldn't have put Spanish in there but anyways...

Comment: I'll remove the Spanish part.

Comment: You've just created a whole different puzzle...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136433/discussion-between-number-basher-and-xyldke).

Comment: If your new answer is right, how do you explain the old (confusing) clues?

Comment: These are correct.